# rails 4.2.0 console broken with 'file is already defined'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently using rails 4.2.0 & ruby 2.2.0p0
re-bundled to pick up some gem updates
RAILS_ENV=production rails c fails with the following stack trace

> /home/linkee/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require': File is already defined (NameError)
>           from /home/linkee/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in`block (2 levels) in require'
>           from /home/linkee/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
>           from /home/linkee/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`block in require'
>           from /home/linkee/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
>           from /home/linkee/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in`require'
>           from /home/linkee/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
>           from /home/linkee/linker/config/application.rb:14:in`'
>           from /home/linkee/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require'
>           from /home/linkee/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in`require_application_and_environment!'
>           from /home/linkee/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
>           from /home/linkee/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
>           from /home/linkee/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /home/linkee/linker/bin/rails:4:in`require'
>           from /home/linkee/linker/bin/rails:4:in `'

I note that the runtime.rb fails when trying to require 'zipruby' so I excluded that gem from being required by changing line 76 in require.rb to

```
pp required_file = file
Kernel.require(file) unless file == 'zipruby'
```

and that at least bypassed whatever the problem was.

Please let me know if you require further information to help in sorting out this problem.

Comment: Probably related to the zipruby gem's last release being over 5 years ago.

Comment: that was it. if you'd like to recast your comment as an answer that'd be great.